# Delete data from plist file archive

Tags: ios

I use plist to save data as shown below. I need now to delete this data, either all of them or certain record - message in my case - from the plist file , how to do that?

```
NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self.messages forKey:@"Messages"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self messagesPath] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just unarchive the same way using an `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to get your original data back. Then, assuming it is a `NSDictionary` and you make a mutable copy of it, you can remove keys from it just as normal.